# Slice and assign a matrix from a matrix class using a proxy class in C++

Tags: c++, class, templates, matrix

I would like to have a simple matrix class with the feature of slicing to avoid nested for-loops. For that, I have written the following class

```
// matrix.hpp

#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class SubMatrix;

template <typename T>
class Matrix
{
    std::vector<T> _matrix;
    size_t _rows;
    size_t _cols;

public:
    Matrix(const size_t rows, const size_t cols) : _matrix(rows * cols),
                                                   _rows(rows),
                                                   _cols(cols) {}

    Matrix(const size_t rows, const size_t cols, const T init)
        : _matrix(rows * cols, init),
          _rows(rows),
          _cols(cols) {}

    Matrix(Matrix &other) : _matrix(other._matrix),
                            _rows(other._rows),
                            _cols(other._cols) {}

    ~Matrix() {}

    Matrix &operator=(Matrix &other)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < _matrix.size(); ++i)
            _matrix[i] = other._matrix[i];

        _rows = other.rows();
        _cols = other.cols();

        return *this;
    }

    T operator()(const size_t i, const size_t j) const
    {
        return _matrix.at(_cols * i + j);
    }

    T &operator()(const size_t i, const size_t j)
    {
        return _matrix.at(_cols * i + j);
    }

    /*
        i, j: initial row and column, respectively
        p: number of rows from i
        q: number of columns from j
    */

    void slice(const size_t i, const size_t j,
               const size_t p, const size_t q,
               Matrix &other)
    {
        size_t index{0};
        size_t cont{0};

        for (size_t ii = i; ii < i + p; ii++)
        {
            for (size_t jj = j; jj < j + q; jj++)
            {
                index = _cols * ii + jj;
                _matrix[index] = other._matrix[cont];

                ++cont;
            }
        }
    }

    void print()
    {
        std::cout << '\n';
        for (size_t i = 0; i < _rows; ++i)
        {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < _cols; ++j)
                std::cout << this->operator()(i, j) << ' ';

            std::cout << '\n';
        }
    }

    SubMatrix<T> operator()(const size_t i,
                            const size_t j,
                            const size_t p,
                            const size_t q)
    {
        SubMatrix<T> sub_matrix(i, j, p, q, *this);
        return sub_matrix;
    }
};
```

To have the slicing feature as

```
A(i, j, p, q) = B
```

where `A` and `B` are matrices, `i` and `j` are the initial indices, and `p` and `q` are the number of lines from `i` and `q` the number of lines from `j`, I have written the following proxy class

```
template <typename T>
class SubMatrix
{
    size_t _i, _j, _p, _q;

public:
    Matrix<T> _matrix;

    SubMatrix(const size_t i,
              const size_t j,
              const size_t p,
              const size_t q,
              Matrix<T> &matrix) : _i(i),
                                   _j(j),
                                   _p(p),
                                   _q(q),
                                   _matrix(matrix) {}

    SubMatrix<T> &operator=(Matrix<T> &matrix)
    {
        _matrix.slice(_i, _j, _p, _q, matrix);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

The code ran smoothly, but the slicing is not being performed correctly. The matrix `B` is not assigned to `A`.

```
// main.cpp

#include "matrix.h"

int main()
{
    Matrix<double> A(5, 5, 1.0);
    Matrix<double> B(3, 3, 9.0);

    A.print();

    B.print();

    A(1, 1, 3, 3) = B;
    A.print();


    return 0;
}
```

The output of the code is:

```
1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 

9 9 9 
9 9 9 
9 9 9 

1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1
```

Does anyone know why the values of `B` is not being assigned to `A`?

Comment: details matter, please make sure the code you post matches the output you post

Comment: Not an answer but this might be interesting to you : [Multidimensional C++ - Bryce Adelstein Lelbach - CppNorth 2022](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aFCLmQEkPUw). It is about [std::mdspan](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/mdspan) C++23. Which is there to make views on multidimensional data.

Comment: @OlafDietsche, sorry, it was a typo.

Comment: your submatrix stores a copy as member `Matrix<T> _matrix;` theres no way modifying this member will modify automagically the original matrix. Maybe you wanted a reference as member

Comment: It's because of a very important part of C++ called "value vs reference". Do you know what references are, in C++, and how to use them? You do understand that your `SubMatrix` contains a completely different `Matrix` object that has nothing to do, whatsoever, with the `Matrix` that it came from? It's almost like the shown code uses objects like they work in Java or C#. C++ is not Java or C#.

Comment: you should try the concept with something much simpler. Something like a `struct twoNumbers { int a,b; };` and now implement a proxy that enables you to assing to either `a` or `b`. It will be much less code but you can have the same problem you have now

Comment: frankly its a little odd that you are using advanced features like templates and operator overloading, but are not aware of value semantics.

Comment: recommendation: Don't do stuff like ` size_t _i, _j, _p, _q;` to yourself. Give things descriptive names so you and other readers don't have to figure out what `_i` represents and is supposed to be used for. It also really sucks when you find you just spent hours debugging because you mixed up _i` and `_j` and the brain kept seeing what it expected rather than the reality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SubMatrix<T> Matrix::operator()` creates a temporary copy of its own internal `_matrix` member. Next this copy is modified by the assignment from `B`.

But the original `A` remains unchanged. When you use a [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) instead, the assignment operator will assign to the original `_matrix` member:

```
template <typename T>
class SubMatrix
{
// ...
    Matrix<T> &_matrix;
public:
// ...
};
```

---

Unrelated, but `_matrix` should be a private member.

Answer (score 1):

What your code does is basically this:

```
#include <iostream>


struct Proxy { int x; };

struct twoNumbers { 
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    Proxy aset() {return {a};}
    Proxy bset() {return {b};}
};

int main() {
    twoNumbers A;
    auto p = A.aset();
    p.x = 42;
    std::cout << A.a;
}
```

The `Proxy` stores a copy of the value and modifying that copy has no effect on the original value.

What you want is `Proxy` holding a reference that allows to modify the original. Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>


struct Proxy { int& x; };

struct twoNumbers { 
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    Proxy aset() {return {a};}
    Proxy bset() {return {b};}
};

int main() {
    twoNumbers A;
    auto p = A.aset();
    p.x = 42;
    std::cout << A.a;
}
```

[output](https://godbolt.org/z/fxfPjTo3e):

```
42
```